# Как фиксировать заголовок сверху, пока видна секция

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5

Я пытаюсь создать эффект,- когда  пользователь прокручивает страницу, заголовок `h1` прилипает к верхней части окна.

Когда родительский `div` прокручен, `h1` затем освобождается и снова прокручивается как обычно.

Когда появится следующий раздел, я хотел бы снова закрепить в верхней части окна следующий `h1` и так далее.

Пример: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Vk9G/1/)

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        $('section h1').addClass('fixed');
    })
})
```

Я также пробовал:

```
var section = $('section');
distance = section.offset().top,
$window = $(window);

$window.scroll(function() {
    if ( $window.scrollTop() >= distance ) {
       section.find('h1').addClass('fixed');
    }
});
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [Fix title to top when section is visible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22758599/7394871) от участника  [@Liam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/766532/liam).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22758599/fix-title-to-top-when-section-is-visible/23338289#23338289

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Потребуется `position: sticky` и [полифилл](https://github.com/filamentgroup/fixed-sticky) к нему.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/kqaatz90/1/).

```css
section {
  position: relative;
}

h1 {
  position: sticky;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid;
}

h1 + p {
  margin-top: 2em;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <p>On teada-tuntud fakt, et lehe kujunduse vaatamisel juhib selle loetav sisu lugeja tähelepanu kõrvale. Lorem Ipsumi kasutamise mõte seisneb selles, et sellel on enam-vähem normaalne jaotus tähti, mitte nagu korduvatel sõnadel "sisu siin, sisu siin", nähes välja nagu tavaline loetav tekst. Paljud tekstiredaktorid ja veebilehtede valmistamise programmid kasutavad Lorem Ipsumit vaikimisi mudeltekstina, ja trükkides otsingusse "lorem ipsum" võib leida veebilehti, mida ei ole veel nende õige sisuga täidetud. Aastatega on tekkinud mitmeid versioone, mõnikord kogemata, mõnikord meelega (huumori sisestamisega jne).</p>
</section>

<section>
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <p>On teada-tuntud fakt, et lehe kujunduse vaatamisel juhib selle loetav sisu lugeja tähelepanu kõrvale. Lorem Ipsumi kasutamise mõte seisneb selles, et sellel on enam-vähem normaalne jaotus tähti, mitte nagu korduvatel sõnadel "sisu siin, sisu siin", nähes välja nagu tavaline loetav tekst. Paljud tekstiredaktorid ja veebilehtede valmistamise programmid kasutavad Lorem Ipsumit vaikimisi mudeltekstina, ja trükkides otsingusse "lorem ipsum" võib leida veebilehti, mida ei ole veel nende õige sisuga täidetud. Aastatega on tekkinud mitmeid versioone, mõnikord kogemata, mõnikord meelega (huumori sisestamisega jne).</p>
</section>

<section>
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <p>On teada-tuntud fakt, et lehe kujunduse vaatamisel juhib selle loetav sisu lugeja tähelepanu kõrvale. Lorem Ipsumi kasutamise mõte seisneb selles, et sellel on enam-vähem normaalne jaotus tähti, mitte nagu korduvatel sõnadel "sisu siin, sisu siin", nähes välja nagu tavaline loetav tekst. Paljud tekstiredaktorid ja veebilehtede valmistamise programmid kasutavad Lorem Ipsumit vaikimisi mudeltekstina, ja trükkides otsingusse "lorem ipsum" võib leida veebilehti, mida ei ole veel nende õige sisuga täidetud. Aastatega on tekkinud mitmeid versioone, mõnikord kogemata, mõnikord meelega (huumori sisestamisega jne).</p>
</section>

<section>
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <p>On teada-tuntud fakt, et lehe kujunduse vaatamisel juhib selle loetav sisu lugeja tähelepanu kõrvale. Lorem Ipsumi kasutamise mõte seisneb selles, et sellel on enam-vähem normaalne jaotus tähti, mitte nagu korduvatel sõnadel "sisu siin, sisu siin", nähes välja nagu tavaline loetav tekst. Paljud tekstiredaktorid ja veebilehtede valmistamise programmid kasutavad Lorem Ipsumit vaikimisi mudeltekstina, ja trükkides otsingusse "lorem ipsum" võib leida veebilehti, mida ei ole veel nende õige sisuga täidetud. Aastatega on tekkinud mitmeid versioone, mõnikord kogemata, mõnikord meelega (huumori sisestamisega jne).</p>
</section>

<section>
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <p>On teada-tuntud fakt, et lehe kujunduse vaatamisel juhib selle loetav sisu lugeja tähelepanu kõrvale. Lorem Ipsumi kasutamise mõte seisneb selles, et sellel on enam-vähem normaalne jaotus tähti, mitte nagu korduvatel sõnadel "sisu siin, sisu siin", nähes välja nagu tavaline loetav tekst. Paljud tekstiredaktorid ja veebilehtede valmistamise programmid kasutavad Lorem Ipsumit vaikimisi mudeltekstina, ja trükkides otsingusse "lorem ipsum" võib leida veebilehti, mida ei ole veel nende õige sisuga täidetud. Aastatega on tekkinud mitmeid versioone, mõnikord kogemata, mõnikord meelega (huumori sisestamisega jne).</p>
</section>
```

Comment: Добавил с полифиллом и -webkit-sticky для ios.

Comment: столько h1 на одной страничке ;), но ответ супер

Comment: @Alexandr_T в хроме всё отлично, ага.

Comment: @HamSter всего-лишь выполняю условия задачи )

Comment: @Alexandr_T, у меня, если что, все ок в хроме

Answer (score 4):

Вы можете сделать это, используя немного `jQuery`

Следующий фрагмент вычисляет `offset` каждого раздела в верхней части окна.

Когда раздел попадает в верхнюю часть окна, его заголовок `h1` изменяется на позицию: `fixed;`.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/spnSZ/)

**jQuery:**

```js
function fixTitle() {
    $('section.affix').each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var offset = $this.offset().top;
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scrollTop > offset) {
            $this.addClass('fixed');
        } else {
            $this.removeClass('fixed');
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $(window).scroll(fixTitle);
});
```

```css
section {
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:0 20%;
    position:relative;
}
section h1 {
    float:left;
    width:17%;
    background:#fff;
}
section .summary {
    float:right;
    width:70%;
}
.fixed h1:first-child {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script> 
<section class="affix">
     <h1>Title 1</h1>

    <div class="summary">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris in justo lectus. Praesent suscipit lacus malesuada, lacinia libero sit amet, placerat justo. Praesent aliquam dignissim tellus quis feugiat. Aenean ac varius nulla. Suspendisse nec mauris ac ligula tempor pharetra ut ac massa. Aenean lacinia consectetur facilisis. Proin eget velit mi. Duis metus risus, viverra ac lacus eu, vestibulum condimentum diam. Fusce molestie nulla felis, sit amet volutpat enim elementum vel. Praesent libero augue, scelerisque in lacus eget, malesuada vestibulum tellus. Curabitur vel nisi enim. In congue, urna vel rhoncus accumsan, velit neque ultrices diam, at dapibus erat ante et augue. Etiam enim tellus, accumsan a velit id, mollis tincidunt augue. Morbi ullamcorper ipsum feugiat vestibulum egestas. Proin porta lacus id sollicitudin vulputate. Nullam tristique neque ac velit lacinia, ut suscipit ligula accumsan.</p>
        <p>Aliquam porttitor id erat et tempus. Aliquam interdum quis lacus ac mollis. Nullam sit amet rutrum leo, vitae fringilla quam. Praesent at lacus et est cursus dictum sed ut elit. Suspendisse sed hendrerit arcu, vel consequat tellus. Cras in tellus commodo, ultricies velit ac, euismod dolor. Donec sollicitudin nisi sit amet augue porta interdum. Vestibulum pulvinar, nisl vel condimentum auctor, nisl dolor laoreet lorem, eget laoreet nunc eros a velit. Cras fermentum ipsum id posuere dignissim.</p>
        <p>Donec vehicula justo sit amet dui euismod dapibus. Sed nulla lacus, lacinia id placerat at, eleifend id libero. Nam gravida neque eu tellus euismod, a consectetur ante interdum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed ut felis at orci tristique mollis. Donec quis tristique urna. Nunc vitae tristique quam. Cras non urna molestie, aliquam nunc sit amet, venenatis dolor.</p>
        <p>Donec nisi enim, lacinia id molestie non, pharetra vel sapien. Duis egestas fringilla ipsum eget iaculis. Integer ultrices accumsan nunc, eget viverra lectus congue eget. Etiam pharetra dolor eget neque accumsan, vel vestibulum ante condimentum. Duis a risus ac turpis mattis mollis vel vitae libero. Proin viverra lectus ut interdum elementum. Nulla ornare ante lobortis purus faucibus iaculis. Duis tempus pharetra tristique.</p>
        <p>In imperdiet ligula eget ligula interdum, eget dictum felis porta. Quisque eu tellus non mi dignissim aliquet. Suspendisse mollis lobortis quam, eu ultrices lectus bibendum eu. Sed at urna nec arcu vulputate lobortis. Sed quis semper ante. Morbi tincidunt felis risus, sed venenatis massa pharetra id. Praesent aliquam scelerisque interdum. Proin libero mi, accumsan lobortis semper vel, tincidunt at nisl. Aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="affix">
     <h1>Title 2</h1>

    <div class="summary">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris in justo lectus. Praesent suscipit lacus malesuada, lacinia libero sit amet, placerat justo. Praesent aliquam dignissim tellus quis feugiat. Aenean ac varius nulla. Suspendisse nec mauris ac ligula tempor pharetra ut ac massa. Aenean lacinia consectetur facilisis. Proin eget velit mi. Duis metus risus, viverra ac lacus eu, vestibulum condimentum diam. Fusce molestie nulla felis, sit amet volutpat enim elementum vel. Praesent libero augue, scelerisque in lacus eget, malesuada vestibulum tellus. Curabitur vel nisi enim. In congue, urna vel rhoncus accumsan, velit neque ultrices diam, at dapibus erat ante et augue. Etiam enim tellus, accumsan a velit id, mollis tincidunt augue. Morbi ullamcorper ipsum feugiat vestibulum egestas. Proin porta lacus id sollicitudin vulputate. Nullam tristique neque ac velit lacinia, ut suscipit ligula accumsan.</p>
        <p>Aliquam porttitor id erat et tempus. Aliquam interdum quis lacus ac mollis. Nullam sit amet rutrum leo, vitae fringilla quam. Praesent at lacus et est cursus dictum sed ut elit. Suspendisse sed hendrerit arcu, vel consequat tellus. Cras in tellus commodo, ultricies velit ac, euismod dolor. Donec sollicitudin nisi sit amet augue porta interdum. Vestibulum pulvinar, nisl vel condimentum auctor, nisl dolor laoreet lorem, eget laoreet nunc eros a velit. Cras fermentum ipsum id posuere dignissim.</p>
        <p>Donec vehicula justo sit amet dui euismod dapibus. Sed nulla lacus, lacinia id placerat at, eleifend id libero. Nam gravida neque eu tellus euismod, a consectetur ante interdum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed ut felis at orci tristique mollis. Donec quis tristique urna. Nunc vitae tristique quam. Cras non urna molestie, aliquam nunc sit amet, venenatis dolor.</p>
        <p>Donec nisi enim, lacinia id molestie non, pharetra vel sapien. Duis egestas fringilla ipsum eget iaculis. Integer ultrices accumsan nunc, eget viverra lectus congue eget. Etiam pharetra dolor eget neque accumsan, vel vestibulum ante condimentum. Duis a risus ac turpis mattis mollis vel vitae libero. Proin viverra lectus ut interdum elementum. Nulla ornare ante lobortis purus faucibus iaculis. Duis tempus pharetra tristique.</p>
        <p>In imperdiet ligula eget ligula interdum, eget dictum felis porta. Quisque eu tellus non mi dignissim aliquet. Suspendisse mollis lobortis quam, eu ultrices lectus bibendum eu. Sed at urna nec arcu vulputate lobortis. Sed quis semper ante. Morbi tincidunt felis risus, sed venenatis massa pharetra id. Praesent aliquam scelerisque interdum. Proin libero mi, accumsan lobortis semper vel, tincidunt at nisl. Aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="affix">
     <h1>Title 3</h1>

    <div class="summary">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris in justo lectus. Praesent suscipit lacus malesuada, lacinia libero sit amet, placerat justo. Praesent aliquam dignissim tellus quis feugiat. Aenean ac varius nulla. Suspendisse nec mauris ac ligula tempor pharetra ut ac massa. Aenean lacinia consectetur facilisis. Proin eget velit mi. Duis metus risus, viverra ac lacus eu, vestibulum condimentum diam. Fusce molestie nulla felis, sit amet volutpat enim elementum vel. Praesent libero augue, scelerisque in lacus eget, malesuada vestibulum tellus. Curabitur vel nisi enim. In congue, urna vel rhoncus accumsan, velit neque ultrices diam, at dapibus erat ante et augue. Etiam enim tellus, accumsan a velit id, mollis tincidunt augue. Morbi ullamcorper ipsum feugiat vestibulum egestas. Proin porta lacus id sollicitudin vulputate. Nullam tristique neque ac velit lacinia, ut suscipit ligula accumsan.</p>
        <p>Aliquam porttitor id erat et tempus. Aliquam interdum quis lacus ac mollis. Nullam sit amet rutrum leo, vitae fringilla quam. Praesent at lacus et est cursus dictum sed ut elit. Suspendisse sed hendrerit arcu, vel consequat tellus. Cras in tellus commodo, ultricies velit ac, euismod dolor. Donec sollicitudin nisi sit amet augue porta interdum. Vestibulum pulvinar, nisl vel condimentum auctor, nisl dolor laoreet lorem, eget laoreet nunc eros a velit. Cras fermentum ipsum id posuere dignissim.</p>
        <p>Donec vehicula justo sit amet dui euismod dapibus. Sed nulla lacus, lacinia id placerat at, eleifend id libero. Nam gravida neque eu tellus euismod, a consectetur ante interdum. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Sed ut felis at orci tristique mollis. Donec quis tristique urna. Nunc vitae tristique quam. Cras non urna molestie, aliquam nunc sit amet, venenatis dolor.</p>
        <p>Donec nisi enim, lacinia id molestie non, pharetra vel sapien. Duis egestas fringilla ipsum eget iaculis. Integer ultrices accumsan nunc, eget viverra lectus congue eget. Etiam pharetra dolor eget neque accumsan, vel vestibulum ante condimentum. Duis a risus ac turpis mattis mollis vel vitae libero. Proin viverra lectus ut interdum elementum. Nulla ornare ante lobortis purus faucibus iaculis. Duis tempus pharetra tristique.</p>
        <p>In imperdiet ligula eget ligula interdum, eget dictum felis porta. Quisque eu tellus non mi dignissim aliquet. Suspendisse mollis lobortis quam, eu ultrices lectus bibendum eu. Sed at urna nec arcu vulputate lobortis. Sed quis semper ante. Morbi tincidunt felis risus, sed venenatis massa pharetra id. Praesent aliquam scelerisque interdum. Proin libero mi, accumsan lobortis semper vel, tincidunt at nisl. Aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
    </div>
</section>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23338289/7394871) от участника  [@web-tiki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1811992/web-tiki).</sub>

Comment: Последняя правка - это что, SEO какое-то? В чём смысл?

Comment: @vp_arth  В марте 2020 были очень большие разборки по соблюдению атрибутов лицензии на переводных топиках с Enso/ Пришли к соглашению, что именно в таком виде  **<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](ссылка на ответ) от участника  [@имя автора](ссылка на профиль).</sub>** необходимо указывать атрибуты лицензии. Все свежие переводы именно так и оформляются. Старые переводы я потихоньку правлю

Comment: Копирастия, понятно, спасибо)